# call javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, message, call

I try to show to user a message with javascript. I have a button and this button does something like,

```
Label1.Text = "Hello world";
//javascript code
```

Firstly, label1.text will "Hello world" after user will see the message.

thanks.

Comment: Same question: Where is the question?

Comment: The question is: What is the javascript code to do what is described. Don't downvote what you may have forgotten you had to go through yourselves.

Comment: i can't show a message to user, if I use "OnclientClick" properties, the javascript function fires first, then label1.text works.

I need to show "Hello world", then user will get a message but I can't do it.

Comment: sorry anyone else i forgot the question. thank you slashmais , you're right.

Comment: @Can: please explain in single steps exactly what you what to do. Edit your question, with with those steps, numbered if you wish, so that the people can understand what you want. These are highly competent people, they will give you exactly the right answer!

Comment: @slashmais, I'm not sure that they'll give all the code needed to do a copy and paste, which is a generally loathed practice I believe.  However, editing the question to get better answers is part of why there is this site and the ability to edit things.

Comment: @JB King: "..copy and paste.." not by me! not by a long shot! I've been in this business long enough to truly believe in c&p!

Answer (score 2):

C# and javascript code run in different timeframes and in different computers. Your server-side code runs and generates HTML which is then sent to browser. The browser then runs javascript code.

Therefore, you can't do stuff like setting the label text in C# and then run javascript. You can't 'call' javascript from C# or C# from javascript.

What you can do, however, is set the label text (which is rendered as a span in browser) in javascript and then do other stuff you wanted to do.

Comment: that's about as close as i could make out as well

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you need an event handler on the button.

```
<button id="somebutton">Click me</button>
<label for="someid"></label>
```

The button can be any html, I just want to show the id, actually.

```
document.getElementById('somebutton').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('someid').innerHTML = 'Hello World';
  return false;
};
```

You can also just append a child to the label adding a textnode, if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are asking here.  I am not aware of a an HTML label.  If you are speaking of an ASP:Label, that is rendered as a span in the browser.  To set the value in JavaScript, you should access it using the document model.  Below might help, if not, please try to clarify your question.

```
<HTML>

<head>
<script>
function changeText()
{
   document.getElementById('spnSayHello').innerHTML = 'Hello World';
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<span id='spnSayHello' onclick="changeText();">clickme</span>
</body>
</HTML>
```

**UPDATE:**  If I understand you correctly, you are trying to render javascript to the page via your c# code?  You can do this in a number of ways.  The way that I usually do this is using `RegisterStartupScript`  like this:

```
private void writeSomeJs()
{
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.form1.getType(),"jPopUp","<script>alert('Hello World');</script>")
}
```

Comment: I mean with "Hello world", I have c# code in code-behind. there are some code which I can't do it with javascript. So, after the c# codes, i have to show a message to user.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to execute JavaScript code after the Label's text has been set would be the following:

```
Label1.Text = "Hello world" +
    @"<script type=""text/javascript"">
          alert(""Message to show."");
      </script>";
```

Basically, the JavaScript code is placed inside the Label's Text. When the browser loads the page returned by the server, it will process the JavaScript and show the message.

Answer (score 0):

I Suppose this is what you are trying,  I tried out this code its working for me.

```
Label1.Text = "Hello world";

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "click", "alert('Messages');", true);
```

or even you can call javascript function from here

```
Label1.Text = "Hello world"; 
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "click", "function();", true);
```